# App not being shown in the gallery

Tags: google-apps-script

I couldn't find any contact information, so I thought posting here would be the next best thing. I resubmitted an app last week (actually I've done it twice now in case there was some error) and I'm experiencing some problems:

1) the previous version of the app has disappeared from the gallery; and
2) it's taking a huge amount fo time (relative to my other experiences) to get it approved.

Who may I contact to follow up on this since it is quite urgent for our needs.

Many thanks,

Eamonn

Answer (score 0):

There are occasionally delays in the review process for scripts being published to the gallery. If it takes a very long time (weeks) you may want to consider re-submitting the script.